# react-bootstrap modal triggered from main navber

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Fairly noob question. But the `react-bootstrap` docs show how to do this when the button to open the `Modal` is in the same component as the `Modal` itself. So in that case it's fairly trivial to simply call the open method directly from the click handler. But I think a more normal method is when the modal exists as a separate component from the the `Modal`, for example from the `Navbar`.

How is this typically handled? Is there a way to call a method on a different component? Or am I supposed to raise some event (using Reflux or whatever)?

Comment: Do you mind writing some code as well.... Its easy to help that way

Comment: I ended up going with firing a reflux action from the Navbar and listening for it in the ModalDialog so it could switch it's state to visible.